# Requiring unknown module "111"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I want to retrieve data from localhost:4547

[image: here]

So, I have a function named loadText which is suppose to do so in this code :

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import { response } from 'express'

export default function Home(props) {


  const { navigation } = props

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Login Screen</Text>
      <Text>{loadText}</Text>
    </View>
  )

  
  function loadText(){
    fetch('http://192.168.1.14:4547/')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        return (
          alert(JSON.stringfy(responseJson))
        );
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(JSON.stringfy(error));
      });
  }

}
```

**PROBLEM:** I receive the following error on my iphone : [image: error]. Any idea on what module "111" is?

Additional info : Here are all my packages I have installed : [image: package.json]

Comment: Can you try to search via your project `111`? looks like you have `111` in your package.json

Comment: @OleksandrPaiziak I don't have anything with 111 in my package.json. I edited my question so you can have a look at my package.json if needed

Comment: As the answer suggests, just close your bundler and restart it

Comment: `alert(JSON.stringfy` well thats not doing to work

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the Metro blunder, as the error says (The terminal or cmd that has the green loading bars, press `cntrl + shift + c`)

then, try again with `npm start --reset-cache` on your project folder. If this does'nt work, try with sudo, if you're on linux.